# Reduce size by dropping frames without re-encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to significantly reduce filesize by dropping frames and speeding it up.

The following work, but only when re-encoding:

- `ffmpeg -r 1000 -i input.mp4 -r 30 -y output.mp4`
- `ffmpeg -itsscale .01 -i input.mp4 -r 30 -y output.mp4`

Adding `-c copy` breaks them.

- `-r 1000` method does absolutely nothing.
- `-itsscale` produces a sped-up video but doesn't reduce the filesize... Are all the frames stil hiddenly present in the file??

Is there any way to drop frames and reduce the filesize without re-encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just drop frames and get a working video, because some of the
frames depend on the frames that preceded them. This is an optimization
used in many codecs/formats for reducing the file-size.

So you absolutely will need to re-encode if you wish to reduce the size
of a video.

For better solutions, see the post
[How can I reduce a video's size with ffmpeg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg)

The answers to this highly-voted post list various solutions:

- Use the H.265 video format which is much better in that it
  compresses more for the same quality.
- Use `-crf 28` ([link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf)
- Scale down the video size for a smaller resolution.
- If the video doesn't include fast action scenes, lower the frame rate.
- Increase the compression rate.
- Lower the color depth.